# Rotate large images on Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to rotate the large images made by the phone camera (8 megapixels). Just Bitmap.createBitmap with the rotated Matrix from the source Bitmap runs into OutOfMemoryError. That's why I'm trying to split into rotated pieces, and than combine them again into single rotated image to avoid holding in memory 2 large Bitmaps, but it takes up to 10 seconds even on my Samsung S3. Any other ways to do this?

```
   public static void rotateImage(File file)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();

        // For the number of rows and columns
        int rowsCols = 3;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(-90);

        int chunkHeight, chunkWidth;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);

        int height = options.outHeight;
        int width = options.outWidth;

        chunkHeight = height / rowsCols;
        chunkWidth = width / rowsCols;

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = 1;
        o2.inPurgeable = true;
        o2.inInputShareable = true;
        o2.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file),
                null, o2);

        // Cut the small rotated pieces and save to the files
        int yCoord = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < rowsCols; y++) {
            int xCoord = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < rowsCols; x++) {
                split(chunkHeight, chunkWidth, yCoord, x, xCoord, y, bitmap,
                        matrix, fileList);
                xCoord += chunkWidth;
            }
            yCoord += chunkHeight;
        }
        bitmap.recycle();
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(height, width,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(rotatedBitmap);

        // Combine the small pieces into the one output canvas
        int xCoord;
        xCoord = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < rowsCols; x++) {  
            yCoord = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < rowsCols; y++) {
                combineIntoCanvas(o2, canvas, xCoord, yCoord, fileList);
                yCoord -= chunkWidth;
            }
            xCoord += chunkHeight;
        }

        //Save the bitmap to the file
        rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90,
                new FileOutputStream(file, false));
        rotatedBitmap.recycle();
        Log.add("combined in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    }

    private static void combineIntoCanvas(BitmapFactory.Options o2,
            Canvas canvas, int xCoord, int yCoord, List<File> fileList)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = fileList.get(0);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file),
                null, o2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, xCoord, yCoord, null);
        bitmap.recycle();
        file.delete();
        fileList.remove(0);
    }

    private static void split(int chunkHeight, int chunkWidth, int yCoord,
            int x, int xCoord, int y, Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix,
            List<File> fileList) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Bitmap pieceOfBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, xCoord, yCoord,
                chunkWidth, chunkHeight, matrix, true);
        File splitFile = new File(Globals.IMAGE_BASE_GALLERY_FOLDER() + "temp"
                + x + "_" + y + "." + "jpg");
        fileList.add(splitFile);

        pieceOfBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0,
                new FileOutputStream(splitFile, false));
        pieceOfBitmap.recycle();
    }
```

Comment: give proper samplesize value 
 check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is just using OpenGL to display and manipulate such a big images.
1. Texture memory is not include into application memory limit
2. On all modern devices this proces is accelerated by GPU
3. It makes easy lot of other jobs - scaling, moving, animations etc.

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate with some example code or any useful links? Thanks!

Comment: Look for some OpenGL ES tutorials - a bit to complicated.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you are trying to take the pics taken from the camera.The photos will be too large in size and if the start playing directly with images it will go OutOfMemory. So better change the image to the sample size then try rotating with your code.Try hard to control the number of bitmaps used.Here when you do this optimizing the code will help you a lot since OutOfMemory  is a common issue with bitmaps.this piece of code will help you to decode the image file using samplesize.This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183210/handling-large-bitmap-in-android) may help you

Comment: The task is to retain the original quality of the rotated image to allow users zoom it in and out.

Answer (score 0):

For others like me:

you can have the camera perform the rotation, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16010289/755804